# How to use tikzexternal?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, tikz-external

I use some huge file to plot and for this I changed the tex conf file to increase memory that works.

But I would like use instead external memory for this I try to use tikzexternal.

But I fail.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18, mode=list and make] %, prefix=figures/
\tikzset{external/force remake}
\usepackage{pgfplots, xstring}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}


\newenvironment{footnotetabular}{\footnotesize\tabular}{\endtabular}
\newenvironment{smalltabular}{\small\tabular}{\endtabular}
\newenvironment{tinytabular}{\tiny\tabular}{\endtabular}


\definecolor{rougeClair}{RGB}{191,0,0}
\definecolor{blanc}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
\tikzset{
    % Defines a custom style which generates BOTH, .pdf and .png export
    png export/.style={
        external/system call/.add={}%
        {; convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"}
    }
}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat        = newest,  % <-- moves axis labels near ticklabels (respects tick label widths)
  table/col sep = comma
}

\hypersetup{ urlcolor=blanc }

\title{blah}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{f1.txt} \tableA


%\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage blah
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Plan}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel                  = X,
        ylabel                  = Y,
        height                  = 10cm,
        width                   = 10cm,
        enlarge x limits        = false,
        xmin                    = 10,
        xmax                    = 80,
        x tick label style      = {font=\footnotesize},
        y tick label style      = {font=\footnotesize}
      ]
      \addplot [only marks, mark size = 0.5,  scatter, scatter src=y] table [ x=X, y=Y ] from \tableA;
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

### Result

```
$ pdflatex test.tex

$ make -f test.makefile

pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{test}\input{test}"
...
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
%&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
make: *** [test-figure0.pdf] Erreur 1

$ tail test-figure0.log
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 25606 strings out of 256216
 576400 string characters out of 1917072
 1500001 words of memory out of 1500000
 28286 multiletter control sequences out of 10000+200000
 8657 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 1200000 for 2000
 645 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,17n,74p,770b,1345s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,6000p,200000b,15000s
```

### Whith document class

same result

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18, mode=list and make] %, prefix=figures/
\tikzset{external/force remake}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
\tikzset{
    % Defines a custom style which generates BOTH, .pdf and .png export
    png export/.style={
        external/system call/.add={}%
        {; convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"}
    }
}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat        = newest,  % <-- moves axis labels near ticklabels (respects tick label widths)
  table/col sep = comma
}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{f1.txt} \tableA

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel                  = X,
        ylabel                  = Y,
        height                  = 10cm,
        width                   = 10cm,
        enlarge x limits        = false,
        xmin                    = 10,
        xmax                    = 80,
        x tick label style      = {font=\footnotesize},
        y tick label style      = {font=\footnotesize}
      ]
      \addplot [only marks, mark size = 0.5,  scatter, scatter src=y] table [ x=X, y=Y ] from \tableA;
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** same error with 10 lines from the huge file

### Input file

file: f1.txt

```
i,X,Y
214,55.44,10.4825
3879,66.29,9.2017
215,65.71,340.529
3971,45.59,351.606
3970,44.16,342.988
3973,61.64,13.2072
3972,64.92,8.65114
3975,59.09,7.90864
2264,40.32,406.593
```

Comment: As such, it isn't really a *minimal* example. You should try and identify what is necessary to reproduce the problem: for example, does it work without beamer? Also, you mention that the data file is quite big, but you didn't provide it. Can you test with a smaller (dummy) data file and see if the problem persist?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Same error with a smaller files and with article document class. The second example should be tiny than previous

Comment: Can you post the small data file?

Comment: yes, that is done

Comment: funny thing ... it works for me!

Comment: I have noticed that the output of your `make` doesn't say `restricted \write18 enabled`. Try adding `-enable-write18` to the makefile manually and running `make` again.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Could you make our comments into an answer?

Comment: I started to write the answer, but then it striked me: in `list and make` mode, shell escaping doesn't need to be enabled. I have tested this by explicitely disabling it for both the main file and the figures, and it works without problem. Now I don't understand how we have solved OPs problem.

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry I forgot to notify you above